# What power do I need for my LED string

Tags: led-driver

I am trying to create outside lighting and using 6 identical LED light sources in a string. The 6 lights I am using are individually 11-16v 3W MR16 3W. I want to use a regular 110-120v AC input to power the lights.

The producer of the LED advises to use 12V or max13V for a single light. The light string is 50 feet long and so I want to stick to a chain setup and avoid parallel installation.

I am reading a lot about adapters and resistors but cannot find the right answer to this setup. Hopefully your knowledge can help me out.

My basic knowledge says I would need and 78v AC output. 
Is this thought correct and how can I best achieve this?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: They're not likely to work reliably wired in series. Just wire them in parallel and use a 12V supply, which you should have no problem finding off the shelf - somewhere in the 25 to 30W range.

Comment: The MR16 do not have any issues with parallel like strings of LEDs have.  Each bulb has an LED driver circuit.  Parallel is the way these bulbs were intended to be powered.

Comment: Outside lighting with low voltage (12V) is SAFE, not a shock hazard.   Higher voltage (over 50V) is NOT GENERALLY SAFE in wet locations, unless you have fixtures intended for such use.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you want an LED driver that has a 12V output (easiest to find). Then looks like you'll need 18W (3W * 6 strings). You /can/ wire them in series but parallel would be easier. On Amazon, Meanwell makes a 12V 5A driver that is more than overkill but will work.

On a side note, unless internal circuitry is involved, LEDs are D.C. devices, not AC. Also, for strings of LEDs, you want a constant current driver. The brightness of the LED depends more on current through vs voltage across.

Comment: These MR16 lamps are not just LEDs.  There is a rectifier and current limiter that generally support both 12V AC and DC.  So a 12V constant voltage (CV) supply is used.  A 12 V Constant Current (CC) supply may work but is not required.  Mean Well also makes a 40 Watt $30 HLG CC.  I would use a CV supply.